# If x in <listOfModels.field> syntax

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model X with a ManyToMany field Y, my query returns a list of X's,

How do I do something like:

```
{% if A in X.Y %}
     Test
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:** X is still a querySet (I'm not iterating the set).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You just have to return an actual queryset:

```
{% if A in X.Y.all %}
    Test
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE (based on comment)**

That is not possible with template code, you need to do a filter, and the Django templating language doesn't allow passing parameters to methods. In your view, you can do:

```
X.objects.filter(Y=A).exists()
```

And pass the result into the context to be used in the template, but I'm not sure how that fits with your exact needs.

Comment: That works when I'm iterating my list of X model, in this case I have a querySet of X, which contains a manyToMany of Y, I want to know if A exists in any of the x.y objects.