# Concat results of querySet into one list

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model `X`, containing a `ManyToManyField` `Y`, I'm trying to concatenate the results of a querySet of `X`'s into a list of all the entries in `Y`

I know the "easy" way would be:

```
for x in X:
    for y in x.Y.all():
        list.append(y)
```

The reasoning to this is related to my previous question:
[If x in <listOfModels.field> syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368386/if-x-in-listofmodels-field-syntax)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the query around. You're interested in Ys, so you should query Ys.

```
y_list = Y.objects.filter(x__in=X)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

chain(SomeModel.objects.all(), OtherModel.objects.all(), ...)
```

Just bear in mind that `chain` returns an iterable, which means you can then use it in for loops and such but you can't filter the QuerySets further or do normal list operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try chaining together the queryset objects into a concatenated generator:

```
chained = itertools.chain(*[x.Y.all() for x in X])
print chained
# <itertools.chain object at 0x10100eb90>

for y in chained:
    print y
```